# Can I change the name of the Sharepoint workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I need to change the name of a Sharepoint designer workflow.

There is a simple direct way I can edit it via SPD right clicking the workflow name. However often the simple, apparently straight forward things that cause unforeseen
issues.

Will this affect the functionality of the workflow or application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to breaking all or most existing hyperlinks to that workflow (such as initiation forms, etc.) and the weirdnesses already pointed out, renaming the workflow can negatively affect the running instances of the workflow.

(Sorry, I can't be more specific; I just know that it's not recommended unless necessary. :-/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also rename the workflow by:

1. Open the site with the workflow in SPD
2. Open the workflow in SPD
3. Click the "< Back" button
4. Change the name of the workflow
5. Click Finish to save

AFAIK, renaming the workflow (the way I specified above) will not cause issues.

Comment: But in the sharepoint list view, for the column title where it shows the the workflow status, it still displays the old name workflow name.
Is there a way to change this column name ?